# Android fragment throw me a exception when layout is inflated for the second time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have to create a project using Android Fragment. I get the following exception when I try to display the fragment for the second time:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I found a lot of topics about this very explicit exception but I didn't found the solution for my project. This is the code of my fragment:

```
public class MyFragement extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
        } else {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

            if (parentViewGroup != null) {
                parentViewGroup.removeView(view);
            }
        }

    }
    ....
}
```

The line

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
```

throws the exception when it is executed for the second time. As the exception suggests me I remove the View to the parent when it is destroyed but it doesn't solve the problem.

The XML file (layout/mylayout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FBF3E7"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="none" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is anybody has an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: In your code I don't see the line `view = inflater.inflate(getLayout(), container, false);`. Only a call to inflate() with R.id.mylayout. Which one are you using exactly?

Comment: Why your use `R.id.` not `R.layout` ? I think `R.id.mylayout` alredy exist on parent view and your fragment try add still one `R.id.mylayout` view.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
public class MyFragement extends Fragment {

private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.id.mylayout, container, false);   
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}
....
```

}

Comment: With your code I get the following exception : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: you have write like
inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file_name, container, false);

Comment: write this...
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40289/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-reevolt)